# CSS for a certain size of the screen (iframe in my case)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm working on a website which will be loaded in a iframe like all the application, if I'm not mistaken, in facebook are loaded. The frame has, obviously, a fixed size 600 x 800 px. Thus I have to correct the css styles.

What's the better way to "simulate" 600 x 800 **size** of the iframe so I can see what the website will look when it's loaded via the iframe? I can't just resize the browser because it doesn't show its size in pixels.

Comment: Not really sure is this is what you're looking for but take a look over [here](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In chrome there is a `device mode` where you can change the size of the screen to what ever you want. Press `F12` and in the top-left corner of the window, there is a device icon. This will simulate any website you go on with your specifications.

You can `Control + Shift + M` to do this in Firefox!
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

IE,Firefox and Chrome all have options that allow you to display a page at a certaint resolution

- [Chrome device mode](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode)
- [Firefox Responsive design view](https://developer.mozilla.org/ro/docs/Tools/Responsive_Design_View) Ctrl+Shift+M
- [IE emulation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn255001%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

In chrome dont't forget to refresh the page after you "Toggle device mode"